# Can not connect mac mini to a 17inch screen

Tags: mac-mini, screen

I am trying to connect my mac mini MD387D/A to a 17 inch Samsung screen Sync Master 730 which has around 9 years and supports up to 1280*1024.

I have a VGA adapter from my mac mini which worked before with two other screens of 24 and 27 inches.

The monitor behaves as follows: when I start my mac mini, the apple starting screen appears with the apple in the middle and the load icon beneath it, after a couple of second, the monitor goes black and says that there is no signal.

Could someone guide me towards a solution, or do I need a new monitor?

EDIT: I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007476KRY) specs that says: *Screen Resolution  1920x1200* does this imply that it is what I should at least have?

Answer (score 1):

There are few places you need to look

- About this Mac-> displays (to see if it shows there under correct name)
- In sys pref ->displays- does it show there as correct monitor

  - Select Mirroring in here
- A console report from the time stamp when you plug it in

Comment: How can I get that info if I do not have a screen?

Comment: sorry, I assumed that was the second screen you are talking about.-- in that case try starting in safe mode with minimal display demand.